# Adding to database field on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In a div on my page called total_records is a database field binding which counts up the total records submitted. i use jquery for the submission so the page doesn't refresh when i click on the button. But i'm only able to get the total records submitted when i refresh the page or press F5. i know there a way out to add 1 to the binding on the page on button click but i don't know how. this is the jquery i use for the submission

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form2").on('submit',function(event){
        $("#comment_loader").fadeIn(); //show when submitting
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.asp",
            data: data
        }).success(function(msg) {
            $('#new_entry').html(msg);
            $("#comment_loader").fadeOut('fast'); 

            $("#msg_div").append("<div class='messages' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Your comment has been saved </div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 3000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How is the value stored? What does the database field look like?

Comment: i count the total number of records submitted by a query which a drag as a binding to the div

Answer (score 0):

Either you can have have the `insert.asp` script return the **total number of records submitted** or within `success` you can call the script that runs the appropriate query and in either case you can use jQuery to update the div with the number returned:

```
$('div.total_records').text( 'number-of-records-submitted' );
```

If you do it this way you would not need to refresh the page.